# Cannot resolve method getAssets() while adding custom font

Tags: android, assets

I want to add custom font to the button (LetterBtn) in my Adapter that extends BaseAdapter, but I get an error with getAssets() as "cannot resolve method 'getAssets()'".

The font is in the assets/fonts/ folder, it works fine in my other Activity.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button letterBtn;

    if (convertView == null) {
        letterBtn = (Button)letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, parent, false);
    } else {
        letterBtn = (Button)convertView;
    }

    letterBtn.setText(letters[position]);


Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
"fonts/nexalight.otf");
letterBtn.setTypeface(font1);

    return letterBtn;

}
```

Comment: Are you using this code in a Fragment?

Comment: Can you please post your full adapter class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are facing this problem in your `Adapter` class. Update your `Adapter` class as below:

```
....................
................................

public class YourAdapter extends ......
{
    .........
    ..............

    Typeface font;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, ...........)
    {
        super(context, ..........);

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/nexalight.otf");
    }

    ...............  
    ........................

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, parent, false);
        } 

        Button letterBtn = (Button ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

        letterBtn.setText(letters[position]);
        letterBtn.setTypeface(font);

        return convertView;
    }

    ...................
    .........................
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
context.getAssets()
```

in adapter, it will work.

```
 Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "HelveticaNeueLTStd55 Roman.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the assets from your view's context. One more optimization you should consider is to save the the `Typeface` in the adapter level so you can reuse it instead of loading it each time from the file.

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button letterBtn;

    if (convertView == null) {
        letterBtn = (Button)letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, parent, false);
    } else {
        letterBtn = (Button)convertView;
    }

    letterBtn.setText(letters[position]);

    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(letterBtn.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/nexalight.otf");
    letterBtn.setTypeface(betuTipus1);

    return letterBtn;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ButtonBold extends Button {
    public ButtonBold(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTypeface();
    }

    public ButtonBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeface();
    }

    public ButtonBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setTypeface();
    }

    private void setTypeface() {
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Utils.BOLD_FACE);
        }
    }
}
```

Utils.BoldFace:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf");
```

Comment: And try another font, maybe problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **context.** before **getAssets(),**

```
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/font.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(custom_font);
```